# Error in IComparable and in lambda expression

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub SetStatusText(ByVal text As String)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim a As Action(Of String) = Function(s) SetStatusText(s)  ' <---- ERROR
            Me.Invoke(a, text)
        Else
            txtStatus.Text = text
        End If
    End Sub
```

**ERROR** : `Expression does not produce a value.`
Why that error what getting? I was testing a code and that part is lambda expression.

### **EDIT**: Solved the above error by changing the `Function` to `Sub`.

==================================================================================

```
Public MustInherit Class Particle
    Implements IComparable(Of Particle)      ' <----- ERROR

    '...

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Particle) As Integer
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("other")
        End If

        If Me Is other OrElse Me.Cost = other.Cost Then
            Return 0
        End If

        If Me.Cost > other.Cost Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return -1
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

**ERROR**: `Class 'Particle' must implement 'Function CompareTo(other As ParticleSwarm.Particle) As Integer' for interface 'System.IComparable(Of Particle)'`

Here, `Particle` and `ParticleSwarm` are different classes. But why that error is appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class must Implement the function like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class Particle
   Implements IComparable(Of Particle) 

Public Property Cost As Integer

Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Particle) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Particle).CompareTo
  If other Is Nothing Then
    Throw New ArgumentNullException("other")
  End If

  If Me Is other OrElse Me.Cost = other.Cost Then
    Return 0
  End If

  If Me.Cost > other.Cost Then
    Return 1
  Else
    Return -1
  End If
End Function

End Class
```

Then lets simplify how we delegate to UI:

```
Private Sub SetStatusText(ByVal text As String)
    Me.Invoke(Sub()
                'we are on the UI thread here
                txtStatus.Text = text 
              End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That was charming :)